# Drools Expert with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, drools

I am using Spring MVC with Drools expert.spring version 4.0.0  drools version(6.0.1)
I am using RAD 8 and WAS 8
The application fails to start with an exception(see below)
The spring integration works just fine in a batch mode. It fails when I invoke it from a web application
The moment I add the kie postprocessor to the application context the web app fails.

```
<bean id="kiePostProcessor" 
class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>
```

Here is the stack trace.

> Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
>       [3/21/14 10:16:11:264 EDT] 0000009f DispatcherSer I     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
>   [3/21/14 10:16:11:265 EDT] 0000009f DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed
>                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.io.File.(File.java:233)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.getPomProperties(ClasspathKieProject.java:228)
>       at org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1680)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1160)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:766)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1354)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2150)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5363)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5579)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1246)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1481)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1370)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1319)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)

Answer (score 0):

This a defect in the `kie-spring` module (6.1.0-FINAL version). You should use the following dependency. This solved it for me.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
   <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0.Beta1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I want to share the research I did on this.
If any one wants to use spring mvc and drools with "websphere" this might be useful.
**This will only be useful if you are using maven.
1. Copy all the dsl and dslr file to the src/main/resources folder in your maven web project.
2. place your kmodule file in src/main/webapp/META-INF/kmodule.xml
3. place a file src\main\webapp\META-INF\maven\\artifactname\pom.properties
note that the pom.properties file should be a regular maven pom.properties file containing

```
version=<version>  
groupId=<packagename>  
artifactId=<artifactid>
```

Now your web project will work just fine.
The above is a work around for the problem that kie has with obtaining dsl and drl files from a jar file. Kie cannot read and process kmodule.xml file from a jar file because it does not support wsjar protocol.

Also I did not use the kie-spring integration since that was giving me a lot of issues.
Hope this helps. Also beta versions cannot be use in our organization.